# what is the difference between event bus and mixins in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Actually, I work in web app with vuejs as frontend framework.

in a particular situation, I want to communicate two separate components.

I know there are many ways to do that, especially with vuex that can help us to create a maintainable application.

in my case, i found we can manipulate data between components by bus events and with mixins (by `$emit` and `$on` event) also.

for that, i want to know :

1. how bus events and mixin work exactly ?
2. what is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) is a partial component spec. You include mixins in a component to compose functionality.

An [event bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) is a communication channel on which events can be emitted and listened for. Every Vue instance is an event bus.

Comment: for mixin, that means if we have a function for example and we need it in many components, we can make it inside a mixin and use it as a global function for our Vue instance ?

Comment: Not as a global, but you can include it in each component that needs it. See the documentation that "mixin" links to.

Comment: Is there a drawback to creating an eventbus AS a mixin? I've done that in my app and it seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if there will be consequences down the road.

Comment: I don't see any inherent problem with it.